# Is there a workaround to use hook data in non-react component functions?

Tags: reactjs

I need to access to some hook data in a util function, possibly without having to pass that data as parameter to the util function.
To be more specific I have a hook that holds user data like the userID.
I also have a util function that takes whatever parameter is passed to it and sends a GTM event with the window.dataLayer.
I need to attach to every call of the util function the userID that comes from the hook, and I'd like to just do it inside the declaration of the util function instead of searching for every call of that function, grab the userID and pass to it.
Since we cannot use hooks inside non-react components, is there a way to get this done?
This is my util function:

```
export const GTMsendEvent = (props: EcommerceEventProps) => {
  if (dataLayerExists()) {

    const filteredItems: EcommerceEventProps = {
      event: props.event
    };

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(props)) {
      if (key !== 'event' && props[key] !== undefined && props[key] !== null && props[key] !== '') {
        filteredItems[key] = value
      }
    }

    (window as any).dataLayer.push({
      ...filteredItems,
      // userID would go here if I can get it from the hook
    });
    console.log('dataLayer: ', (window as any).dataLayer);
  }
};
```

While the hook is simply:

```
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';
const user = useAuth()
```

I could easily fix this by saving the user into a localStorage or sessionStorage and using its value inside the util function but I don't feel like it is a clean solution.

EDIT:
this is the useAuth, which returns the context:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext<any>(AuthContext);
};
```

and this is the return of the AuthContext

```
return (
    <Authenticator
        hideSignUp={true}
        formFields={formFields}
        components={components}
        services={services}
    >
        {({ user, signOut }) => {

            const value: any = {
                user,
                signOut,
                userRole: user?.attributes?.['custom:role'] as ROLE,
            };

            return (
                <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
            );
        }}
    </Authenticator>
);
```

Comment: What does `useAuth` do, which you want to replicate outside a component? You say it "holds user data", but can you be more specific, preferably showing code?

Comment: You could use sessionStorage and that will make it accessible everywhere when the session is active.

Comment: @NicholasTower yes sorry, I edited adding that code

Comment: @SharpDev Yes I could but I'd prefer to get it from the hook, which it takes it from the context and adding it into the sessionStorage it feels like redundant since it is in the context

Comment: You can just use a global variable, or one stashed on `window`, such as `window.__MYAPP_USER_ID`. There's nothing wrong with that if you know what you're doing.

Comment: I'm concerned if I got your idea. Is it a non-react app using jsx? Anyway, to persist the information using context pattern. I need to understand the architecture and the life cycle of the components you're building. Context is simple to understand, but there are some patterns to persist the information, like Observer. I don't feel comfortable suggesting a solution without understanding more.